# Formally Prove that the Ratio of Fibonacci Numbers is Always Greater than 1.5

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Consider the Fibonacci number $1,2,3,5,8,13,21,\cdots.$ It is well known that the limit of the ratio of Fibonacci numbers tends to the Golden Ratio $\phi$. Today, I want to show that $1.5$ is the smallest ratio between any two fibonacci numbers (achieved by $\frac{3}{2}$).

It is evident by inspection, but I was looking for a more formal proof of this.

I've tried using an induction argument, but it hasn't worked. Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There may be an easier approach, but I would start by showing the ratios alternate between being above and below $\phi$.  Then I would show that the ratios below $\phi$ are increasing by taking one ratio to be $\phi-x$, doing two iterations to find the next ratio below $\phi$, and finding the error is less than $x$.  This doesn't come with a guarantee as I didn't fill in the steps.

Comment: The sequence often starts with $1,1$ or $0,1$; in that case the smaller ratio $\frac11=1$ is obtained

Comment: I am ignoring the $\frac{1}{1} = 1$ for now. @RossMillikan, how would I necessarily do what you suggested? For example, let's say we have consecutive Fibonacci numbers $a, a(\phi - x), a(1 + \phi - x), a(2\phi - 2x + 1)$, would I just show that the next ratio has a smaller delta?

Comment: So the next ratio below $\phi$ is $\frac {2\phi -2x +1}{\phi-x+1}$ You want to show this is greater than $\phi-x$

Comment: Looking at Wolfram Alpha, that ratio is less than $x$ for $1.26236<x<2.61803$. However, in our case $x$ would likely be somewhere from $0$ to $\phi - 1$ because all Fibonacci numbers must be increasing. This doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the ratio of the ($n+1$)-th and $n$-th Fibonacci
numbers:
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{a_{n}+a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}=1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n}}.
$$
This quantity is at least as large as $3 / 2$ if only and if $2a_{n-1}\geq a_{n}$.
Or, written in another way,
$$
a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}\geq a_{n}.
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Good. I would also rephrase this answer as: Let the induction proposition be a stronger statement$$\frac32 \le\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\le 2$$.